# Are there other builds in Dungeon Raid?

Tags: dungeon-raid

The character classes in Dungeon Raid seem like they should add variety to gameplay, but for me they mostly don't. I wonder whether that's because I'm not seeing the value of their bonuses, so I'm just playing the same strategy every time anyway.

In my experience, the thing to do is balance all your stats, and hold out for things in the same group of five or six skills (Skill Elixir, Boost Armour, Dazzle, Teleport, Treasure, Enchant). Always take Blunting, Quicken or Regen if offered; don't bother with Poison and Spikes.

This presumably isn't the very best strategy, but it's done okay for me, and the only character class that's benefitted from a different style is the Raider, who's easy to score much higher with but who I also don't see much way to customize beneficially.

Am I missing whole play patterns that Mage or Elf or Barbarian would enable, or am I overestimating how much variety the classes/species/new skills should add?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its worth trying out poison with elves, the racial bonus - half damage from poisoned enemies - allows you to play a game based more on endurance.

Poison is also useful when:

- There arent enough swords on the grid
- The meatshield special enemy is on the grid, as you can still damage normal skulls.
- Flame or Spike special enemys (as you dont have to touch them much)
- That special enemy that requires you to strike 3 in a row below it (forget the name!) - can still be poisonsed and damaged.

Answer (score 0):

I agree. I like the Elf's ability as well, and it is one of the few Race or Class abilities that makes a difference in how you play - you take Poison more often than you would otherwise.

I also find myself taking the same skills : Enchant, Skill Elixir, Teleport, Banish, Disarm. I tried out Treasure and Dazzle a couple times, but never really tried Boost Armor. I think you need Banish and Teleport because a couple of my longer games I got beat by a Mage coming in after a Banish, and then I can't get rid of him.

As far as enchants go, I also find myself taking the same each time : regen and blunting whenever they're offered.

I also taking Armor Piercing and the opposite one that saves your armor more. I thought about trying an armor-centric one with these and repair/Dex, but still don't understand how +1 repair works.